# Flutter layout issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm testing out flutter, but ran into an issue trying to create a specific layout. I'm trying to create a card with 2 parts. At the top is an image spanning the full width of the card and with a set height. Below that is a Container with several Text widgets laid out in a Column. I then wish to add some padding to the bottom container and offset it so it overlaps the bottom of the image.

[image: Layout of the card]

I've tried doing this using a Stack, see the code below, but my issue is that from what I understand the Stack widget takes it size from all non-positioned widgets. This means the Stack only gets the size of the image and the Container gets cut of at the bottom of the image. The content of the Container is also of variable length, so I can not set a fixed height, but need the card to size itself to it's content, both the image and the Container.

```
return Card(
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Image.network(
        "https://imbo.vgc.no/users/e24/images/5f2fdecdbd09cfad22aa84e922a3e7c7?t%5B0%5D=crop%3Awidth%3D4027%2Cheight%3D2263%2Cx%3D0%2Cy%3D356&t%5B1%5D=maxSize%3Awidth%3D990&t%5B2%5D=resize%3Awidth%3D990&accessToken=e04754e3d904710cb41dc49bb02df916894bdf5a801c49a5965195cee3c86936",
        height: 200.0,
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 175.0,
        left: 10.0,
        right: 10.0,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("This is the header", style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1.0), fontSize: 20.0)),
              Text("This is some content of variable length", style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1.0)))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],        
  ),
);
```

This is a simple version of my code, I've tried all sorts of different variations without achieving what I wish. I would appreciate any help or hints to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Looks like just using a column and moving the bottom container up with transform might be a solution, I'll test it

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set `overflow` ?

```
Stack(overflow: Overflow.visible ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried it, and while it makes the text display, it will overflow outside the wrapping Card widget. I need the Card to size itself to all the content, which is whats causing me the problems, as it seems a positioned widget is not including when calculating the size. This also leads to problems if adding more widgets below this one as the overflowed content will be positioned behind whatever is placed below instead of pushing it further down

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Transform.translate` Widget to "move up" your `Container` into to the `Image`.

```
Transform.translate{
  offset: Offset(xAxisOffset, yAxisOffset),
 child: //your Container
}
```

Check out the *Flutter Widget of the Week* Video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9z_YNlRlWfA or read the Documentation for more information about the Widget: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to add
alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter for Stack widget.

Refer below code:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Card(
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.network(
                  "https://imbo.vgc.no/users/e24/images/5f2fdecdbd09cfad22aa84e922a3e7c7?t%5B0%5D=crop%3Awidth%3D4027%2Cheight%3D2263%2Cx%3D0%2Cy%3D356&t%5B1%5D=maxSize%3Awidth%3D990&t%5B2%5D=resize%3Awidth%3D990&accessToken=e04754e3d904710cb41dc49bb02df916894bdf5a801c49a5965195cee3c86936",
                  height: 200.0,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 10.0,
                  right: 10.0,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("This is the header",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1.0),
                                fontSize: 20.0)),
                        Text("This is some content of variable length",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1.0)))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Output:

[image]